# load word/pdf/text files according to localization/lang in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-6

Our laravel application is localized and we have an aggrement file in pdf format. we will have different aggrement files depending on locale so we need to load it according to it. 
as far as i have known we can check locale using **App::isLocale()** and load according to it.. or is there any better way to get file according to locale